# Add extra query param in Javascript whilst keeping original URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a button in body that once clicked, it should add an extra query parameter in the URL.

```
let addParam;
const button = document.createElement("BUTTON");
button.textContent = "Add";
document.body.prepend(button);

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  url.searchParams.set("param", "value");

  window.history.pushState({ path: url.href }, "", url.href);
  addParam = addParam ? false : true;
});
```

It works fine, the problem is that the current URL contains already a query parameter in the form of `?path=path/to/file`, so when we set another parameter with `set(key, value)`, it changes the `?path=path/to/file` to `?path=path%2Fto%2Ffile`. Is there a way I can prevent that from happening and keeping the original URL?

Comment: `path%2Fto%2Ffile` is perfectly valid. It is properly encoded! If whatever is using that value has a problem with it, then code should be fixed to decode it properly.

Comment: Side note: The more idiomatic way to write `addParam = addParam ? false : true;` is `addParam = !addParam;` :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both URLs mean the same thing. I'm guessing you prefer the one with `/` instead of the encoded form of it because it's more obvious to people reading the URL.

This may vary by browser, but on Chromium-based browsers it seems that it keeps the `/` if it's in the URL you pass to `pushState`. It's the `URLSearchParams` that's encoding the `/`.

I originally posted a solution doing string concatenation with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead, but my solution was doing an [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append), not a [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set). Your code is using `set`. Fortunately I'd also included a second solution: You can convert `%2F` to `/` after adding to the search params and converting them to a string:

```
const { origin, pathname, search } = window.location;
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(search);
searchParams.set("param", "value");
const paramsString = searchParams.toString().replace(/%2f/gi, "/");
const url = `${origin}${pathname}?${paramsString}`;

window.history.pushState({ path: url }, "", url);
addParam = addParam ? false : true;
```

Note that I don't *advocate* this. I'd stick with the code you have. But it's your project, so you get to decide. :-)

Comment: Turns out no need to string check, new URL accepts Location `var url = new URL(window.location); url.searchParams.append('data', 'value')`

Comment: @savageGoat - I'm afraid I don't know what you mean by that. But note that [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set) and [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) do different things. And thank you for noting it, because my first code block does `append`, but the OP is using `set`. I'd best fix that.

Comment: I mean no need to pass a string like `window.location.href`, `window.location` is a `Location` type object but the Url constructor accepts the `Location` object so it removes all the problems related to the parameters

Comment: @savageGoat - The problem isn't in that part, it's converting back to string after updating the params. That's when `/` is converted to `%2F`.

Comment: You are right, my bad. `Array.from(url.searchParams.entries())` returns the path but as soon as you pass it as encoded you still have to decode the path

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you, this is what I was looking for. One thing, when I am refreshing the pages a few times, the pathname seems to multiply for some reason, everytime I refresh. I mean, the URL would end up looking like this `http://localhost:3000/////?path=path/to/something&param=value`. Do you happen to have an idea why that might be? Maybe one reason could be that I'm putting the whole code in a window.onload event listener and it could mess something up? (before you ask, it's been there so I had to work inside of it)

Comment: @kristalshards - If it's when you *refresh* the page, it wouldn't be related to the code above, which just works with the URL that's there. I've put this code in a page and refreshed it several times both before and after adding the parameter, and it doesn't do that at this end.